# VS Code doesn't detect unhandled errors written in GO

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, goland, golangci-lint

VSCode doesn't show a warning on unhandled error.

I've got this line of code:

`defer resp.Body.Close()`

which is market as unhandled error in GOLAND IDE but in VSCode I don't get similar nice
warning as in GOLAND.

I've got `golangci-lint` as my linter, go extension installed, confugured linter in settings, got my linter file in the root directory of my project:

```
linters:
  enable:
    - errcheck
    - gofmt
    - govet
    - golint
    - gocyclo
    - ineffassign
    - structcheck
    - varcheck
    - deadcode
    - unconvert

linters-settings:
  errcheck:
    check-type-assertions: false
    check-blank: true
```

Got these settings in `settings.json`:

```
  "gopls": {
    "ui.semanticTokens": true
  },
  "[go]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
    // "editor.defaultFormatter": "golang.go"
  },
  "go.lintTool": "golangci-lint",
  "go.lintFlags": ["--fast"]
```

Running `golangci-lint run -v` command also throws errors but not the one which I am expecting.

Only thing I could find is this issue on github, which I couldn't understand https://github.com/solo-io/gloo/issues/6686